# Background-image для QLineEdit

Tags: qt, c++

Как сделать фон из картинки для `QLineEdit`? Пытался задать таблицу стилей:

```
QLineEdit: {
  background-image:url(:/images/13.png);
}
```

Не сработало.

Answer (score 2):

1 вариант:

```
QLineEdit { 
   image: url(:/images/13.png);
}
```

2 вариант (самый лучший):
Оставить как есть, но задать значение `false` свойству `frame`:

```
lineEdit->setFrame(false);
```